# Retrieving the actual class inside a Listener

Tags: android, http, task, listener

I have a class in my Android app that implements an Inteface.

This is the call.

`public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements HttpAsyncTaskInterface`

I have a HttpAsyncTask where I have to set a class that implements this Interface.
My problem is that I'm creating de HttpAsynkTask object inside a spinner listener and I don't know how to reference my class.

```
 private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener myOnItemClickListener() {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (!mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(JSONConverterUtils.SPINNER_PROMPT)) {
                        HttpAsyncTask httpAsyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask(2);
                        **httpAsyncTask.setHttpAsyncTaskInterface();**
                        httpAsyncTask.execute(URL);
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        };
    }
```

I need to put my SearchFragment reference in this line `httpAsyncTask.setHttpAsyncTaskInterface(this);`

But this doesn't work because the call it's inside the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
httpAsyncTask.setHttpAsyncTaskInterface(SearchFragment.this);
```

Will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
httpAsyncTask.setHttpAsyncTaskInterface(mSearchFragment.this);
```